# artisan backpack:build fails with BadMethodCallException

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In a fresh Backpack installation, when I run `php artisan backpack:build` it fails as follows:

```
   BadMethodCallException                                                        
                                                                                 
  Method Illuminate\Support\Stringable::value does not exist.                    
                                                                                 
  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113  
    109▕      */                                                                 
    110▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)                        
    111▕     {                                                                   
    112▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {                              
  ➜ 113▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(                   
    114▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method 
    115▕             ));                                                         
    116▕         }                                                               
    117▕                                                                         
                                                                                 
  • Bad Method Call: Did you mean Illuminate\Support\Stringable::headline() ?    
                                                                                 
      +16 vendor frames                                                          
  17  artisan:37                                                                 
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I'm running php 7.3.33 and laravel 8.83.27 and backpack/crud: 5.4.16 and backpack/generators: v3.3.13

UPDATE 2/15/23: I've updated the server to php 7.4.33, but the problem is unchanged.

Is this a bug, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like we have a bug in the current Backpack Generators + Laravel 8. That's because `Stringable::value()` [was added in Laravel 9](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/d7cf744ca1601c27410dd6b8b4d1cb7389bd3039), not L8.

I've created and merged a PR that fixes this - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Generators/pull/185

After a `composer update backpack/generators` you should be good to go!